# Getting UL certification for neon signs

Tags: safety, ul

I make neon lights and have been for 10years on my own and just recently found out that I could get in alot of trouble for not having my signs UL certification done. I want to make it right and want to know how to go about getting my certifications done so I can correct this so how would I go about getting it me certified in UL lighting.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the title to sound less spammy.

Comment: Contact your local UL office and ask for a quotation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you misunderstand UL certification. "You" cannot get certified. Only your product can. Furthermore, each different product would need to be certified separately. This would involve providing at least 3 samples for destructive testing, money in the range of $10K+, and a wait in the range of a year.

For a maker of custom neon signs, I can't imagine that this would be a good idea.

If you like, you can get a copy of UL48 (electric signs, including neon) and see what standards would be applied to your signs, and use this as a guide in building them.

But take Adam Lawrence's advice, and get your information from UL, rather than some stranger on the internet.

Comment: That would be awesome

Comment: To build on what WhatRoughBeast said, some product categories work with more flexibility at UL. Industrial Control Panels, for instance, give very general guidelines and allow the manufacturer to custom-build each panel for his customers, as long as he stays within guidelines. I would imagine there is something similar for neon signs, as they will intentionally be different each time. I would contact them directly and find out.

Answer (score 0):

Many businesses sell products that are not UL certified.
http://ul.com/corporate/faq/general/background/
"Manufacturers submit products to UL for testing and safety certification on a voluntary basis. There are no laws specifying that a UL Mark must be used. However, in the United States there are many municipalities that have laws, codes or regulations which require a product to be tested by a nationally recognized testing laboratory before it can be sold in their area. UL is the largest and oldest nationally recognized testing laboratory in the United States. UL does not, however, maintain a list of the jurisdictions having such regulations."